# Regex - get nearest match group from keyword

Tags: regex

I have an issue with regex, I don't know how to explain it. but maybe it's better to use an example here: (fixing my title post are welcomed)

I have this javascript script which looks like this:

```
...
someFunction(Vo = Co(!0, {
  id: "Shape.c6e2778",
  other_attribute: "4",
  name: "Square"
}), Vo = Co(!0, {
  id: "Shape.3151b12",
  other_attribute: "3",
  name: "Triangle"
}))
```

What I want to get is the shape id for shape named `"Triangle"` (the id should be **3151b12**)

Right now my regex looks like this:

```
id:\s+"Shape\.([^"]+)",[\S\s]*?name: "Triangle"
```

But I get **c6e2778** which is the id of Square not Triangle. how do I match shape id that is closest to `name: "Triangle"` keyword?

Hope this is clear enough.

You can what I did on: https://regexr.com/7jp5j
Thank you

Comment: Why are you using regex instead of JSON to parse JSON?

Comment: `[\S\s*]*` is greedy. It grabs everything from the first ID to the last name.

Comment: yeah it should use regex. I just simplify things so I only put it as json. but actually what I want to parse is from html javascript content

Comment: You may just use: `id:\s+"Shape\.([^"]+)",\s*name:\s+"Triangle"`

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/E3UCZG/1, but you need to parse JSON with a JSON parser.

Comment: @anubhava thanks! that works. but I forgot, the real object is in this format:
```
{
  id: "Shape.c6e2778",
  other_attribute: "4",
  name: "Square"
}, {
  id: "Shape.3151b12",
  other_attribute: "3",
  name: "Triangle"
}
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist look at sample, it's not JSON because keys are not quoted

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It's my fault because I said it's on json format. I just updated the question.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/E3UCZG/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks man! That works. I just have a extra question (hope you didn't mind to answer). I saw you're using `(?:,\s*\w+:\s*".*")*?` to match any other key value between the object. while I'm using `[\S\s]*?` which also will match anything with lazy mode `*?` but it didn't work. what is happening?

Comment: Oh I just figured it out. it's because your regex won't match `}), Vo = Co(!0, {`.

Again, Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex to get you match within a block of `{...}`:

```bash
id:\s*"Shape\.([^"]+)",(?:[^{}\n]*\n)*\s*name:\s*"Triangle"
```

[RegEx DEmo](https://regex101.com/r/XR9N3z/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `id:`: Match text `id:`
- `\s*`: Match 0+ whitespaces
- `"Shape\.`: Match text `Shape.`
- `([^"]+)`: Match 1+ of any characters that are not `"` and capture in group #1
- `",`: Match text `",`
- `(?:[^{}\n]*\n)*`: Match 0 or more of any characters that are not `{`, `}` and `\n` followed by a line break. Repeat this group 0 or more times.
- `\s*name:\s*`: Match text `name:` surrounded with optional whitespaces
- `"Triangle"`: Match text `"Triangle"`